# Send recording by mail to recipients in twilio voice call

Tags: c#, .net, twilio

I want to send recording by mail to recipients in twilio voice call when call completed. Can anyone please suggest how to achieve it?

Comment: Welcome.   Any chance you can post what code you have tried so far?   This will help us help you.   Otherwise it kinda makes your question too broad. [ask].  Good luck!

Comment: Whilst there is nothing wrong with answering your _own_ questions, be sure that your question is written well.  As of the time of writing, your question has 3 close votes. Consider expanding on your question. [ask].  Wishing you well.

Comment: Please suggest if anyone have idea how to transfer call to user line,mobile,web twilio after receive. Any api reference?

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution, we can achieve this by setting RecordingStatusCallback while receiving or making call and then handle RecordingStatusCallback, send the recording to recipient according to requirement as:

```
 public CallResource MakeOutboundPhoneCallsAsync(OutgoingCallRequest request, string accountSid, string authToken, Guid userId)
    {
        try
        {
            TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
            List<string> statusCallbackEvent = new List<string> { "answered", "completed" };
            CallResource response =
                CallResource.Create(
                            url: new Uri("http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"),
                            to: new PhoneNumber(request.ToPhoneNumber),
                            from: new PhoneNumber(request.FromPhoneNumber),
                            method: Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Get,
                            record: request.Record,
                            recordingStatusCallback: baseUrl + "/api/Twilio/OutboundCalls/RecordingStatusCallback",
                            recordingStatusCallbackMethod: Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Post
                        );

            return response;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

and then handle call back as in your controller:

```
 [HttpPost("RecordingStatusCallback")]
    public IActionResult RecordingStatusCallback()
    {        
            //Get callback values here and write code To send email
    }
```

Comment: Whilst there is nothing wrong with answering your _own_ questions, be sure that your question is written well.  As of the time of writing, your question has 3 close votes. Consider expanding on your question. [ask].  Wishing you well.